# Facebook API: Get user permission for email and avoid CANCEL loop

Tags: facebook, zend-framework

I am developing a facebook application. I am serving a webpage which is going to be an iFrame within a facebook fan page. The problem is that, I can't manage to  handle with the case when the user clicks on the cabncel (don't allow) button (it loops).

Could anyone send me a simple example how to deal with the request for permission? Let's say I need only access to the user email and I want to redirect to the page wall when the user hits cancel, thus not going in a loop.

This is some of the code from the controller

```
$this->facebook = Zend_Registry::get('facebook');
$signed_request = $this->facebook->getSignedRequest();
$this->view->hasAllowed = isset($signed_request['oauth_token']) ? true : false;
```

and this is from the view:

```
<?php if(!$this->hasAllowed): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   top.location.href = '<?= $this->oauth_url ?>';
</script>
<?php endif;?>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.init({
      appId  : '<?=$this->app_id?>',
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/):

> If the user presses Don't Allow, your app is not authorized. The OAuth Dialog will redirect (via HTTP 302) the user's browser to the URL you passed in the redirect_uri parameter with the following error information: http://YOUR_URL?error_reason=user_denied&   error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.

So your issue currently is that if a user clicks "Don't allow", you're displaying the same view which includes the same JS login code, restarting the process. All you need to do is check in your callback action for the `error_reason` param, and if present and set to `user_denied`, redirect to the app wall page instead:

```
public function callbackAction()
{
    if ($this->_hasParam('error_reason') && $this->_getParam('error_reason') == 'user_denied') {
        $this->_helper->Redirector->setGotoUrl('http://example.com/yourapppage');
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could render a different view which explained to the user why your app requires the permissions it does, and give them the option to login again.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what's your `$this->oauth_url`, but it has to be something like this:

```
top.location.href="http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=APP_ID&method=permissions.request&display=page&next=URL_TO_GO_WHEN_USER_ACCEPT&cancel_url=URL_TO_GO_WHEN_USER_CANCEL&response_type=token&canvas=1&perms=email";
```

Probably, what you need is the `cancel_url` parameter, that redirect the user to this url if he doesn't allow.

Hope it helps!